# es.merge usage in gulp: Object #<Stream> has no method 'end'

Tags: node.js, gulp, event-stream

I am struggling to get two parallel processing routes to work in gulp. My code looks like this:

```
gulp.task('build', function(){

    return gulp.src(src,{cwd:srcDir})
        .pipe(concat('sdk.js', {newLine:'\n\n'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(es.merge(
            gulp.src('dist/sdk.js')
                .pipe(preprocess({context:{debug:true}}))
                .pipe(rename('sdk.debug.js')),
            gulp.src('dist/sdk.js')
                .pipe(preprocess({context:{}}))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(rename('sdk.min.js'))
        ))
        //some more processing
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
        ;
});
```

I have found a suggestion [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/177#issuecomment-32913011) that such a way of forking and then merging streams should work. However, I get the error:

```
stream.js:79
    dest.end();
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Stream> has no method 'end'
    at Stream.onend (stream.js:79:10)
    at Stream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at end (C:\Users\user\Documents\proj\node-sdk\node_modules\gulp-
jshint\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:116:39)
    at Stream.stream.end (C:\Users\user\Documents\proj\node-sdk\node
_modules\gulp-jshint\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:122:5)
    at Stream.onend (stream.js:79:10)
    at Stream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at end (C:\Users\user\Documents\proj\node-sdk\node_modules\gulp-
jshint\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:116:39)
    at queueData (C:\Users\user\Documents\proj\node-sdk\node_modules
\gulp-jshint\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:62:17)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Documents\proj\node-sdk\node_modules\gulp
-jshint\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:71:7)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\proj\node-sdk\node_modules\gulp-jshin
t\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:85:7
```

It seems that the problem lies with the usage of es.merge, as without it (one processing path) everything works as expected. Unfortunately, I don't have an extensive knowledge of node.js streams, so I cannot identify the cause of this problem.
My version of Node is 0.10.28, gulp 3.6.2 and event-stream is 3.1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`es.merge` cannot be used as the target of a pipe because it is not a proper WriteStream. It implements `write()` but not `end()` so it will work to forward along the incoming stream data, but when the upstream source is finished, `es.merge` does not handle the `end` event.  I don't know if this is the intended behavior for `es.merge`, but at least in its current implementation, it can only be used as a source.

https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/blob/master/index.js#L32

An alternate solution would be to split your task into two separate tasks and use gulp dependencies:

```
gulp.task('build-concat', function() {
    return gulp.src(src,{cwd:srcDir})
        .pipe(concat('sdk.js', {newLine:'\n\n'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['build-concat'], function() {
    return es.merge(
        gulp.src('dist/sdk.js')
            .pipe(preprocess({context:{debug:true}}))
            .pipe(rename('sdk.debug.js')),
        gulp.src('dist/sdk.js')
            .pipe(preprocess({context:{}}))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(rename('sdk.min.js'))
    ))
    //some more processing
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
    ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved this eventually in a similar way, splitting the task into three ('build_standard', 'build-debug' and 'build_min')